# How to support Code Parameters and Code Completion for my Packages

Tags: delphi

I ship a Delphi library that includes compiled packages and source code. I'd like users to be able to access the source code as a form of documentation, but not need it to be compiled when they compile their apps.

Note: I realize for this that the DCU folder must be added as a "Library path" and the source added as a "Browsing Path". I will do this using the installer.

What I cannot understand clearly from the documentation is the correct defines to specify to enable code parameters and code completion.

It sounds like I need:

```
{$DEFINITIONINFO ON}
```

Which then require:

```
{$DebugInfo ON}
{$LocalSymbols ON}
```

I'm not entirely clear on how {$ReferenceInfo On} fits into this, but I presume it allows users to Ctrl+click a class to see its reference

Comment: There is no define for adding to the library and/or browsing path. Those are IDE settings, not code settings.

Comment: If the user does not include your source in their project and the DCU exists then the source will not be recompiled even if they 'build' their projects.

Comment: @Ken, sorry, I realize I must manually add the paths to the registry. I will do this using the installer. What I need to know is which defines are required (assuming paths are set) to support code completion and code parameters? (I've edited the description to make it more clear)

Comment: There are no defines needed. The IDE needs to be able to find the .dcus for the symbols, and the source to provide the completion. You can see this yourself in any unit you add to your project - the IDE's parser will compile code, extract symbols, and provide the code parameters (Code Insight and Code Completion) automatically.

Comment: For other readers: I installed delphi on a fresh PC, setting only the library and browsing paths. Ken is correct. The defines do not seem to affect the ability of the IDE to output code insight/completion